# Linq Distinct SQL Statementet

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, distinct, expression-trees

I have tried to use Distinct() with some queryable as below peice of code:

```
var finalWhere = Expression.Lambda<Func<Data.DataModel.TrialSummary, bool>>(containsMethod, parameter);

queryableTrialSummary = queryableTrialSummary.Where(finalWhere).Distinct();

var trials = queryableTrialSummary.Select(x => x.Trial_Code).Distinct();
```

But I have found that the SQL Statement Generated for the distinct is as below;

```
SELECT 
    [Distinct1].[Trial_Code] AS [Trial_Code]
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Extent1].[Trial_Code] AS [Trial_Code]
        FROM [OBAR].[TrialSummary] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Trial_MasterProtocolId] IN (N'15NOPEPYT512')
    )  AS [Distinct1]
```

My Question is: why there are two select statements, one inner and one outer in the above SQL statement.

Did I do something wrong, because I think this should produce something wrong here because I think this should produce SQL statement as below

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Extent1].[Trial_Code] AS [Trial_Code]
        FROM [OBAR].[TrialSummary] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[Trial_MasterProtocolId] IN (N'15NOPEPYT512')
```

Could you please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Question is: why there are two select statements, one inner and one
>   outer in the above SQL statement.

You used two `distinct` command so the generated sql will containing two `distinct` as well. Change your linq to:

```
var trials = queryableTrialSummary.Where(finalWhere).Select(x => x.Trial_Code).Distinct();
```

You can use [linqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) to check you generated SQL.

Comment: @user3494319 Did I answer your question or not?

Answer (score 0):

> Question:
>   why there are two select statements, one inner and one outer in the
>   above SQL statement.

Because you are adding two expressions to your expression tree by doing Distinct twice:

```
queryableTrialSummary.Where(finalWhere).Distinct();
queryableTrialSummary.Select(x => x.Trial_Code).Distinct();
```

Try to understand how IQueryable and IEnumerable work. 
[This is a nice blog to read.](https://blog.falafel.com/understanding-ienumerable-iqueryable-c/)

What you are looking for is:

```
queryableTrialSummary.Where(finalWhere);
queryableTrialSummary.Select(x => x.Trial_Code).Distinct();
```